# V-W switch in Dickens

Tags: orthography, literature, archaicisms

As I was reading Charles Dickens' *Oliver Twist*, I noticed some irregularities in the spelling choices. Specifically, in several words beginning with a *v*, Dickens switched them out with a *w*. Here are some examples:

**1. Vicious- Wicious**

> "this is them wicious paupers!"

**2. Vulgar- Wulgar**

> "if I thought as any one of 'em had dared to lift his wulgar eyes to that lovely countenance--"

**3. Vile- Wile**

> "Say it again, you wile, owdacious fellow!"

My question is the following: is this some archaic form of spelling? When did it fall out of style, and how did it originate?

Comment: You've never heard Elmer Fudd speak?

Comment: It's not an archaic form of spelling ... it's an attempt at a representation of how Cockney sounded at the time Charles Dickens wrote. (As, I presume, is *owdacious*.)

Comment: Ah, zat Pickvick!

Comment: A couple of links where you can read more if you are interested.   http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/09/does-sam-weller-speak-cockney.html  https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=hggNAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=v